# @detail_route: object has no attribute - Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I get an issue about @detail_route. Hope your guys helps!

This is my viewsets. I use decorators to import detail_route

**My viewsets:**

```
class PhotoUpdateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = [
            'image',
            'is_public',
            'caption'
        ]
class UploadAvatarPhotoAPIView(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PhotoUpdateSerializer
    queryset = Photo.objects.all()

    @detail_route(methods=['POST'])
    def upload_avatar(self, request, username):
        avatarqs = Photo.objects.create(
            user=self.request.user,
            caption=self.caption,
            image=self.image,
            is_public=self.is_public
        )
        serializer = PhotoUpdateSerializer(avatarqs)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Error: `'UploadAvatarPhotoAPIView' object has no attribute 'caption'`

I think 3 lines are error:

```
caption=self.caption,
image=self.image,
is_public=self.is_public
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You needed `request.POST` to fetch data.

```
caption = request.POST['caption']
is_public = request.POST['is_public']
```

and for image data

```
image=request.FILES.get('image')
```

**UPDATE**

You need to set `enctype` to `multipart/form-data` in your form tag, to get data in `request.FILES` while uploading file.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Thank you! I made it successfully! Vote for ya

Comment: Sorry, I got this error when post Content_Type: `content_type = ContentType.objects.get(model='photos'),`. Issues: `int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Photos'` Hope your helps!

Comment: do it something like `ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Photo)`, check [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#methods-on-contenttype-instances)

Comment: `int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Photos'` Also get this error.

Comment: you are using `Photos` but your model name is `Photo`.

Comment: @Santendra. This is other Model. It's like Albums, not Photo. Sorry because this name is easy to make mistake

Comment: @FeedGit you can ask this as a separate question, someone will surely help you.